# Please add a block for new users when they try to post multiple answers to the same question

Tags: feature-request, new-users, rate-limiting

About an hour ago a new user on Aviation.SE posted 5 "answers" to the same question in less than 15 minutes.

Only the first was an actual answer, the second was an addition and the remaining were just images.

Can users with less than, say, 50 reputation be blocked from adding more than one answer in these situations, and simply mention to the new user that an "edit" functionality is present.

Answer (score 6):

A warning already exists.  If the user posted 5 answers, they chose to ignore the warnings.

We don't need a block.  The warning is more than sufficient for handling the vast majority of cases, the small handful of cases that happen anyway are easily solved with a flag for deletion.

Comment: I admit I was not aware of the warnings, but anyway I am trying to propose a stronger version: an actual block for multiple answers below a certain rep threshold.

Comment: @Federico But you *didn't* suggest a block, you suggested a warning.

Comment: Ok, it got lost in the long sentence (I now bolded it) but I proposed to show the warning and **prevent** further answers

Comment: @Federico Then it's not a warning anymore.  Then it's just a block.

Comment: do you enjoy this game? or could you actually try to have a positive discussion? the warning/message/whatever name pleases you would be there to explain the user. a block with no explanation is useless.

Comment: @Federico No, I don't particularly enjoy people asking a question, and then getting upset when they get an answer to the question that they asked, instead of the question that they were thinking of but didn't ask.  It's not fun for anyone involved.  It's better when people ask the question they actually want answered.  Note that when you block someone from doing something you can explain why you blocked it.  That doesn't make it a warning, it makes it an explanation for the block.

Comment: I asked it, as it is the body of the first version of the post. I used the wrong name in the title? that's why we have a body. don't blame me for you not reading what I wrote.

Comment: @Federico You asked for there to be a warning.  There is a warning.  You wanted there to be a hard block.  Your question is *still* asking for there to be a warning, not a block.  If you want to propose a block, propose that users <50 rep be blocked from posting more than one answer, rather than a warning.